# Setup RAID 0 for an Asus Zenbook UX301i

Tags: laptop, bios, raid, asus-laptop, raid-0

I've been asked to format and install Linux on the laptop, which has two `128gb SSDs`. `ASUS` suggest `RAID 0` is *fast*, so I want to setup the laptop, as is, but with Linux Mint installed.

https://www.asus.com/uk/Laptops/ASUS-ZenBook-UX301LA/

I've spent a good portion today looking at answers, which suggests hitting `CTRL+i` will get me into some sort of RAID configuration, however this doesn't work.

I have the following options configured within the BIOS:

- SATA mode - `RAID`
- Secure boot - `disabled`
- Fast boot - `disabled`
- Enable CSM - `enabled`

Essentially, what is the RAID configuration tool provided with this laptop? Is it Intel's RST (Rapid Storage Technology), or is it something else? And how do I get into it.

Comment: Make a favor for yourself and never use RAID-0 if storage would have important data because if one drive would fail in such setup - you will loose everything. If cost of drives isn't a problem and data is more important then setup RAID-1(mirror), it will give you almost the same reading speed as RAID-0 and piece of mind.

Comment: Thanks Alex; yup, I understand the difference (and RAID-1 would be my preferred choice); however, getting to this setup seems either impossible or non-existent.

Comment: What operation system system you going to use? For the last decade we switched almost all systems to software RAID instead of hardware based. The reason is - when you motherboard that has embedded RAID or separate card get failed - it's a huge trouble to restore data from disks. If you familiar with Unix based OS, then ZFS is most reliable filesystems  with a lot of advantages that no1 other has. Windows also support software RAID and if you going to use mirrors it behaves the same way on reading as RAID-0 by reading data from different channels doubling reading speed.

Comment: Ideally Linux Mint, but we're open to options. I run a couple of Microservers at home, using FreeNAS, and utilise ZFS, I can also vouch for it. But I've never used ZFS for a desktop; does that work? I've read BTRFS works well with mint.

Comment: ZFS is just a filesystem and works perfectly fine on desktop too. I didn't tried it personally on Mint but I think ZFSonLinux project is very active and Ubuntu (which in turn parent distro for Mint) even has in repositories compiled binaries for ZFS for distribution, so I don't think it is a problem. As about BTRFS, it is dead since redhat announced that they stop supporting it.